# Using JSON objects in 'if' statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, if-statement, getjson

I'm making a site for my game server, and I'm trying to display user information using the Steam API.

```
$.getJSON('/steamapi', function(data) {

  document.getElementById("staff-inner").innerHTML = `${data.response.players.map(function(player) {

    return `

      <div class="player player-${player.steamid}">
      <div class="name">${player.personaname}</div>
      <div class="avatar"><img src="${player.avatarfull}"></div>
      <div class="role"></div>
      </div>

    `;
  }).join('')}`;

});
```

The above code is working fine. But, what I'm trying to do (and I assume this is the best way) is create an if statement that says if ${player.steamid} is my Steam ID, it prints 'Owner' in .role, and prints 'Moderator' if it's anything else. Seems like it would be simple enough, but everything I try leaves me with a blank page. I have no idea how or where I would write it in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a template string, only expressions are allowed, not statements. `if` is a statement; but there's the conditional operator (`?:`) which has almost the same semantics.

```
`...
<div class="role">${player.steamid == 'Rex4748' ? 'Owner' : 'Moderator'}</div>
...`
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can declare a variable before your return statement and call the reference

```
let role = player.steamid == '111' ? 'Owner' : 'Moderator'
```

and then

```
<div class="role">${role}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get enough time to test this with steamAPI but I think it'll work :

```
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');

const my_steam_id = 'Rex4748';

const players = [{
  steamid: 'Rex4748',
  avatarfull: 'https://fakeimg.pl/50/',
  personaname: 'Joe Perez'
},{
  steamid: 'notYou',
  avatarfull: 'https://fakeimg.pl/50/',
  personaname: 'NewGuy'
}]

function getPlayers(){
  let info_collected = [];
  players.map((player)=> {
    console.log(player.steamid);
    info_collected.push(`
      <div class="player player-${player.steamid}">
        <div class="name">
          ${player.personaname}
        </div>
        <div class="avatar">
          <img src="${player.avatarfull}">
        </div>
        <div class="role">
          ${player.steamid == my_steam_id ? 
            'Owner' : 
            'Moderator'}
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    `);
  })
  return info_collected.join('');
}

appDiv.innerHTML = getPlayers();
```

Pen : https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-json-objects-in-if-statements